# creating a function to extract numbers from a list of strings

Tags: python

I need to create a function that takes in a list and only extracts the numbers from that string and this is what I have now.

```
list00 = ["90", "hello", "55", "Hi", "100"]


def abc(list):
    list_of_numbers = []
    for i in list:
        try:
            list_of_numbers.append(int(i[0]))
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(abc(list00))
```

ideally i am expecting it to print out [90,55,100] but the actual output, was "none" in the terminal. why is this happening and how can i fix it

Comment: Remove the `[0]`, and add `return list_of_numbers` at the end of the function.

Comment: You're lacking `return list_of_numbers` at the end of your function.

Comment: @hocuspocuslotus put the `return` after the loop, not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `return` in your function. Also `i[0]` is not good in this context, as it will give you the 0th character from the string, so for `90` you'd get only `9` as an int, not `90`...

```py
from typing import List
items = ["90", "hello", "55", "Hi", "100"]


def extract_numbers(items: List[str])->List[int]:
    numbers = []
    for item in items:
        try:
            numbers.append(int(item))
        except Exception:
            print("Skipping an item which cannot be casted to an int!")
    return numbers

numbers = extract_numbers(items)
print(numbers)
```

Side notes:

- give variables (and functions) meaningful names
- use type hints when possible (it will help later on)
- do not use reserved keywords as names, not ever (e.g. `list`, `dict`, `tuple` etc. is always a bad name)
- `return` from a function if you need its output
- in general do NOT silently `pass` on exception, do some logging or at least a `print`

As for "why was the actual output none":
By default function with no explicit `return` statement (or with `return`, but no `variable` returned) returns `None`.
Give it a try:

```py
def foo():pass

x = foo()
print(x) # It's gonna be None

def bar():
    return

y = bar()
print(y) # The same here
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `return list_of_numbers`. You can also use a comprehension:

```
def abc(lst):
    return [int(i) for i in lst if i.isdigit()]

abc(list00)
```

Output:

```
[90, 55, 100]
```